# R: Creating a Column For Each Element in a List

Tags: r, list

I am working with the R programming language. I have a list ("my_list") that looks something like this - each element in the list (e.g. [[i]]) has a different number of subelements (e.g. [[i]][j]) :

```
 > my_list
    
    my_list
    [[1]]
    [1] "subelement1"   "subelement2"   "subelement3"
    
    [[2]]
    [1] "subelement1"                             "subelement2" "subelement3"         "subelement4"           "subelement5"    
    
    [[3]]
    [1] "subelement1"                           "subelement2"   "subelement3"  "subelement4"         "subelement5"
    
    [[4]]
    [1] "subelement1"                   "subelement2"           "subelement3" "subelement4" "subelement5" 
    
    > summary(my_list)
           Length Class  Mode     
      [1,] 3      -none- character
      [2,] 5      -none- character
      [3,] 5      -none- character
      [4,] 5      -none- character
      [5,] 5      -none- character
      [6,] 5      -none- character
      [7,] 5      -none- character
      [8,] 5      -none- character
      [9,] 5      -none- character
     [10,] 5      -none- character
     [11,] 5      -none- character
     [12,] 6      -none- character
```

For each element in this list, I want to extract each of these subelement and make them into a dataframe all together (each row in this dataframe will not necessarily have the same number of columns). Since I don't the maximum number of subelements, I tried to find out the maximum number of subelements - but some parsing is still involved (many entries in the "Length" column are not numbers for some reason?):

```
summary = summary(my_list)

> summary

    Var1   Var2      Freq
1      A Length         3
2      B Length         5
3      C Length         5
4      D Length         5
5      E Length         5
6      F Length         5
7      G Length         5
8      H Length         5

####

96    R3 Length         5
97    S3 Length         5
98    T3 Length         5
99    U3 Length         5
100   V3 Length         5

####

101    A  Class    -none-
102    B  Class    -none-
103    C  Class    -none-
104    D  Class    -none-

######

296   R3   Mode character
297   S3   Mode character
298   T3   Mode character
299   U3   Mode character
300   V3   Mode character
```

Next:

```
    summary = data.frame(summary)
    freq = as.numeric(gsub("([0-9]+).*$", "\\1", summary$Freq))
     freq = freq[!is.na(freq)]

> max(freq)
[1] 6
```

With this very "roundabout way" - I now know there at most 6 subelements, and I can create 6 corresponding columns:

```
col1 = sapply(my_list,function(x) x[1])
col2 = sapply(my_list,function(x) x[2])
col3 = sapply(my_list,function(x) x[3])
col4 = sapply(my_list,function(x) x[4])
col5 = sapply(my_list,function(x) x[5])
col6 = sapply(my_list,function(x) x[6])

#final answer : desired output
final_data = data.frame(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6)
```

**My Question:** Would there have been an easier way to find out the maximum number of subelements in this list and then create a data frame with the correct number of columns? I.e. Is there an "automatic" way to create a data frame with the same number of columns as subelements in the list and name these columns accordingly (e.g. col1, col2, col3, etc.)?

Thanks!

Comment: d = data.frame(sapply(c("col1"=1, "col2"=2,"col3"=3,"col4"=4,"col5"=5, "col6"=6), \(n) sapply(my_list, \(x) x[n]) )) ... could this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
mx <- max(sapply(my_list , length))

df <- do.call(rbind , lapply(my_list , \(x) if(length(x) == mx) x
 else c(x , rep(NA , mx - length(x)))))

df <- data.frame(df)
colnames(df) <- paste0("col" , 1:mx)
```

- output

```
         col1        col2        col3        col4        col5
1 subelement1 subelement2 subelement3        <NA>        <NA>
2 subelement1 subelement2 subelement3 subelement4 subelement5
3 subelement1 subelement2 subelement3 subelement4 subelement5
4 subelement1 subelement2 subelement3 subelement4 subelement5
```

Comment: @ Mohammed Desouky: Thank you so much - I think this worked! I just added a : 
d = data.frame(do.call(rbind , lapply(my_list , \(x) if(length(x) == mx) x
                       else c(x , rep(NA , mx - length(x))))))

Comment: Updated to make it data.frame with your column names

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is functional, so obviously take this with a grain of salt, but it's possible to find the maximum length of a sublist with one loop.

```
max_length <- 0
lapply(my_list, \(x){if (length(x) > max_length){max_length = length(x)} }
> max_length
[1] 6
```

To make a dataframe with the corresponding columns a similar approach can be used:

```
#create an empty dataframe to add rows to
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = max_length, nrow = 0))
colnames(df) <- sprintf("raster[%d]",seq(1:max_length))

#add rows
lapply(listanswer, \(x){df[nrow(df) + 1,] <- x})
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35712196/how-create-a-sequence-of-strings-with-different-numbers-in-r) regarding `sprintf`. Since you need to know the maximum row length going in, two loops are necessary, one to find the max length, and one to fill the data frame.

Comment: @ Luke : Thank you so much! Is there a way to create a dataframe to store the elements of this list and name the columns accordingly (e.g. col1, col2, etc)?

Comment: yeah, using a similar approach, I'll put it in the response